# Tags within StoreKit receipt

Tags: iphone, web-services, storekit

I'm developing a web service where I need to verify a purchase on the server and return some info if validation is successful. I want to make sure someone can't spoof the service by requesting validation with a receipt from another application. Is there a way to get the product id or some other meaningful information that will let my server verify it's my app requesting validation?

Ken

Answer (score 0):

as far as i remember, the receipt contain productId as well as bundleId so just use those. The receipt validation (at apple side) ensures that the receipt has been not tampered with.

further reading: [Veryfiyng Store Receipts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html)

Comment: The receipt is encoded.  Here's an example:{
 "signature" = "AjGjAWtliuIWOVYPTEeKoC+NAr/JWrtI/bJxGUPIIuCgD7EHlypPP73gx9Px1ysXFUMCpPSkSd6...argOSzQ==";
 "purchase-info" = "ewoJIml0ZW0taWQiID0gIjQ2NTMwOTAwOCI7Cgkib3JpZ2luYWwtdHJhbnNhY3Rpb24taWQiID0gIjEwMDAwMDAwMDgzNDgwMDkiOwoJInB1cmNoYXNlLWRhdGUiID0gIjIwMTEtMDktM...IgPSAiY29tLldlZXNoU29mdC5TdG9yZUtpdFRlc3QiOwoJImJ2cnMiID0gIjEuMCI7Cn0=";
 "environment" = "Sandbox";
 "pod" = "100";
 "signing-status" = "0";
}